# Windows 10 - Right-Click Context Menu, and Settings App Freeze/Hang

Tags: windows-10

The big problem right now is that when I right click certain things like folders/shortcuts everything freezes, I restart explorer and it still happens. I tried DISM, SFC and pretty much all basic troubleshooting steps. When I tried to access the settings app it stays stuck at the loading screen.

I tried doing a few commands in powershell but those too just seem to hang there and do nothing.

Things work fine in Safe Mode so it's something I can probably fix

Comment: Sounds like a so-called Shell Extension could be to blame. You can try disabling some with [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Comment: I did that. And it didn't help. Im fairly certain it was somehow a windows update issue as I did one recently and disabling the windows update service made everything go back to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was fixed by disabling microsoft services in "System Configuration" one by one until I found the one causing the issue. It seems to be an issue with "Windows Update" - wuauserv - weirdly enough

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before. It is likely a context setting that has gone wrong. There are hundreds (approx) of context settings and finding the errant setting is very difficult.

Since you have tried DISM and SFC unsuccessfully, now is the time to do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

**First**, make a new, test, Windows User Profile. Log into the new Profile and test the right click ability in the new profile. If it is profile damage, the profile will have to be replaced.

**Otherwise** proceed to the Repair Install process.

There are 3 possible approaches below for ever increasing error repair. Start with Keep Everything. Read through first and then proceed.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

**Finally,** a failure of all the above methods means you need to back everything up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I've tried disabling every context setting I can and it's done almost nothing. the weird thing is that usually. the context menu eventually appears.

Comment: The are very many context settings and I have never found the errant on. It is very difficult. So I posted a solution that should fix this (and has for me).

Comment: it's stuck at "Making sure you're ready to install"

Comment: If your system will not do a Repair Install (that would be very unusual for systems I have worked on) then you may need to back everything up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I amended my answer to include "nothing works" at the end of the answer

Comment: the settings app keeps crashing so I can't get into the settings to do anything either. To fix settings everything says to use powershell. But that just hangs as well

Comment: This is why I suggested backing up completely and reinstalling Windows.